# Using fscanf to scan a value or use default if no value exists

Tags: c, scanf

I have a function to read a text file with the following format

```
 string int int
 string int int
 string int int
```

I want to write a function that will assign the values from the text file into variables, but there will also be some cases where the format of the text file will be

```
string int
string int
string int
```

In that case, I'd like to set the value of the last int variable to 1. My code I have so far works with the first example but I'm a bit stuck on getting the second scenario to work:

```
void readFile(LinkedList *inList, char* file)
    {
    char tempName[30];
    int tempLoc, tempNum;

    FILE* f;
    f = fopen(file, "r");
    if(f==NULL) 
        {
        printf("Error: could not open file");
        }
    else
        {
        while (fscanf(f, "%s %d %d\n", tempName, &tempLoc, &tempNum) != EOF)
            {
            insertFirst (inList, tempName, tempLoc, tempNum);
            }
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second case, fscanf will return 2 instead of 3.  So you can rewrite the code like this:

```
while (1) {
    int ret = fscanf(f, "%s %d %d\n", tempName, &tempLoc, &tempNum);
    if (ret == EOF) {
        break;
    }
    if (ret == 2) {
        tempNum = 1;
    } else if (ret != 3) {
        // line appear invalid, deal with the error
    }
    insertFirst (inList, tempName, tempLoc, tempNum);
```

}

A more hacky way would be to set tempNum to 1 before calling fscanf and just check for EOF as you did above.  But I think the code above is clearer.

Edit: to avoid overflows, this would be better.  The code would perform better but this is harder to write.  Just like above, I did not write any code for the error conditions but you definitely want to handle them

```
char lineBuf[255];
while (fgets(lineBuf, sizeof(lineBuf), f) != NULL) {
    int spaceIdx, ret;
    const int len = strlen(lineBuf);
    if (len == (sizeof(lineBuf) - 1) {
         // line is too long - either your buf is too small and you should tell the user
         // that its input is bad
         // I recommend to treat this as an error
    }
    lineBuf[len - 1] = '\0'; // remove \n
    --len;  // update len, we've removed one character
    if (isspace(*lineBuf)) {
        // error, line should not start with a space
    }
    spaceIdx = strcspn(lineBuf, "\t ");
    if (spaceIdx == len) {
        // error, no space in this line
    }

    // Ok, we've found the space.  Deal with the rest.
    // Note that for this purpose, sscanf is a bit heavy handed (but makes the code
    // simpler). You could do it with strtol.
    // Also, the first space in the format string is important, so sscanf skips 
    // all the space at the beginning of the string.  If your format requires only
    // one space between fields, you can do sscanf(lineBuf + spaceIdx + 1, "%d %d"...

    ret = sscanf(lineBuf + spaceIdx, " %d %d", &tempLoc, &tempNum);
    if (0 == ret) {
        // error, no ints
    }
    else if (1 == ret) {
        tempNum = 1;
    }

    // at that point, you could copy the first part of lineBuf to tempName, but then
    // you have to deal with a potential overflow (and spend time on an useless copy),
    // so use lineBuf instead

    lineBuf[spaceIdx] = '\0';

    insertFirst (inList, lineBuf, tempLoc, tempNum);
}
```

Comment: How do you make sure tempName is long enough to hold the string?

Comment: To ensure you're not overflowing your buffer, consider using fgets to read the file and then use sscanf